# Is there a built in way to use DateFormatter to get value in the format of "Sun Sep 27 at 4pm"

Tags: swift

I have the following formatter:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
```

My goal is to turn my dates into strings like:

Today at 3pm

Tomorrow at 3pm

Sun Sep 27 at 3pm

It works great for dates that are today or tomorrow, but for dates beyond that I want the following format:

"Sun Sep 27 at 4pm"

When I print the result of `dateFormatter.string(from: DATE)` for a date 3 days from now, I get the following:

`Sep 27, 2020 at 4 PM`

Is there a way to customize the `dateStyle` so I can instead get the desired string?  I messed around with .full, .short, etc. but want to customize it my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **Locale-independent** solution:

1. Check if the `Date` is *relative*:

For this you can use Calendar functions `.isDateInYesterday(date:)` etc.

```
private func isDateRelative(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
    Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(date)
        || Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)
        || Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date)
}
```

2. If it's relative replace the `date` part with the date in the `localizedFormat` but keep the `time` part intact.

---

**`DateFormatter` extension**

```
extension DateFormatter {
    func relativeStringWithFormat(from date: Date, localizedFormat: String) -> String {
        if isDateRelative(date) {
            return relativeDateTimeString(from: date)
        }
        let dateStr = localizedDateString(from: date, localizedFormat: localizedFormat)
        let timeStr = relativeTimeString(from: date)
        return dateStr + timeStr
    }
    
    private func relativeDateTimeString(from date: Date) -> String {
        dateStyle = .medium
        timeStyle = .short
        doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
        return string(from: date)
    }
    
    private func relativeDateString(from date: Date) -> String {
        dateStyle = .medium
        timeStyle = .none
        doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
        return string(from: date)
    }
    
    private func relativeTimeString(from date: Date) -> String {
        relativeDateTimeString(from: date).replacingOccurrences(of: relativeDateString(from: date), with: "")
    }
    
    private func localizedDateString(from date: Date, localizedFormat: String) -> String {
        setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(localizedFormat)
        doesRelativeDateFormatting = false
        return string(from: date)
    }

    private func isDateRelative(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(date)
            || Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)
            || Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date)
    }
}
```

---

**Testing**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

let today = Date()
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)!
let nextWeek = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: today)!

let localizedFormat = "EEE d MMM"
```

```
print(dateFormatter.relativeStringWithFormat(from: today, localizedFormat: localizedFormat))
// Today at 6:20 PM
print(dateFormatter.relativeStringWithFormat(from: tomorrow, localizedFormat: localizedFormat))
// Tomorrow at 6:20 PM
print(dateFormatter.relativeStringWithFormat(from: nextWeek, localizedFormat: localizedFormat))
// Sat, Oct 3 at 6:20 PM
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is nice.  On a side note is there a good swift date library that you recommend?

Comment: @user1354934 I've never used one, it probably depends on what you need.

Comment: You should use Swift's `or` abstraction! `[Calendar.isDateInYesterday, Calendar.isDateInToday, Calendar.isDateInTomorrow].contains { $0(.current)(date) }`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
dateformater.dateformat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Output:
Wed, 12 Sep 2018 14:11:54

Comment: does this mean I need to remove the doesRelativeDateFormatting?

Comment: the Today or Tomorrow at do not work, it shows today date

Comment: Can you share the behaviour after removing doesRelativeDateFormatting ?

Comment: Sorry I tried it again, and it does not work still.  It shows Fri, 25 Sept

Answer (score 1):

Here's a DateFormatter subclass that should give you what you want. Note that I handled the "Yesterday" case even though you didn't mention it in your question. Also note the if you want to display times other than just the hour portion you'll need to adjust the "ha" part of the `dateFormat` string.

```
class MyDateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        amSymbol = "am"
        pmSymbol = "pm"
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func string(from date: Date) -> String {
        setDateFormat(forDate: date)
        return super.string(from: date)
    }

    private func setDateFormat(forDate date: Date) {
        if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date) {
            dateFormat = "'Yesterday' 'at' ha"
            return
        } else if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
            dateFormat = "'Today' 'at' ha"
            return
        } else if calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date) {
            dateFormat = "'Tomorrow' 'at' ha"
            return
        }
        dateFormat = "E MMM d 'at' ha"
    }
}
```

Just use it as you would a normal DateFormatter:

```
let formatter = MyDateFormatter()
let dateStr = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateStr) // Today at 12pm
```

Comment: This is wrong - it will only work for the English language. You shouldn't hardcode dates like that.

Comment: Yeah but its okay for me right now since the other answers don't work.  I'll just not use "at" or substitute manually

Comment: I'm not sure to fair to say its "wrong" simply because its non-localized. The question had very specific instructions on what the output should be given a certain input. With that said, kudos for giving a solution that handles localization.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get what you want would just be

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE MMM d 'at' ha"
```

If you want to ensure the AM and PM are lowercased, you could add

```
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
```